# Ziping a File in python and moving it

Tags: python-2.7, zip

In the script when I have zip it up a file in say C:/Users/User/Desktop/Folder, it shows up as a zip file in the structure of ZipFile.zip/C:/Users/user/Desktop/Folder instead of just ZipFile.zip/Folder and I can't figure out how to fix it. [**Zipping code is lines 21-26**]

I'm also trying to **move the created zip** file to the specified back up device [line 27]

My code is :

```
import os
import sys
import shutil
import zipfile
import traceback

print ('Welcome to USB Backup Utility')
print ('Created by: TheCryptek')
print ('\nWhat directory would you like to back up?')
print ('Example: C:/users/user/Desktop/Folder')
backUp = raw_input('> ') # Files the user specified to back up
print ('\nWhere would you like to back these files up at?')
print ('Example USB Letter: E:/')
backDevice = raw_input('> ') # Device the user specified to save the back up on.
print ('\nName of the zip file you prefer?')
print ('Example: Backup.zip')
backZip = raw_input('> ') # The name of the zip file specified by the user
print ('\nBackup started...')
if not os.path.exists(backDevice + '/BackUp'): # If the BackUp folder doesn't exist on the device then
    os.mkdir(backDevice + 'BackUp') # Make the backup folder on usb device
backZip = zipfile.ZipFile(backZip, 'w') # Not sure what to say for lines 21 - 26
for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk(backUp): 
    backZip.write(dirname)
    for filename in files:
        backZip.write(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
    backZip.close()
shutil.move(backZip, backDevice + '/BackUp') # Move the zip files created in working directory to the specified back up device -[ Something is wrong with this can't figure out what ]-
print('Backup finished.')
```

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for coding help; can you please rephrase your question so it fits [the guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: I don't see anything regarding coding help or is it just the format of my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **shutil.move()** you have to give proper source and destination paths.

And in your program,the source path and file object are of same names.so it is calling that object instead it should take the path of file.

```
import os
import sys
import shutil
import zipfile
import traceback

print ('Welcome to USB Backup Utility')
print ('Created by: TheCryptek')
print ('\nWhat directory would you like to back up?')
print ('Example: C:/users/user/Desktop/Folder')
backUp = raw_input('> ') # Files the user specified to back up
print ('\nWhere would you like to back these files up at?')
print ('Example USB Letter: E:/')
backDevice = raw_input('> ') # Device the user specified to save the back up on.
print ('\nName of the zip file you prefer?')
print ('Example: Backup.zip')
backZip = raw_input('> ') # The name of the zip file specified by the user
print ('\nBackup started...')

if not os.path.exists(backDevice + '/BackUp'): # If the BackUp folder doesn't exist on the device then
    os.mkdir(backDevice + 'BackUp') # Make the backup folder on usb device

bkZip = zipfile.ZipFile(backZip, 'w') # Not sure what to say for lines 21 - 26
for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk(backUp): 
    bkZip.write(dirname)
    for filename in files:
        bkZip.write(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
    bkZip.close()

#print backZip,backDevice
dest = backDevice + '/BackUp'
#print dest
shutil.move(backZip, dest) # Move the zip files created in working directory to the specified back up device -[ Something is wrong with this can't figure out what ]-
print('Backup finished.')
```

Comment: After making the suggested edits I now get this [error](https://ghostbin.com/paste/2phpv)

Comment: @TheCryptek its works fine for me.. Given the following inputs at 1./home/shiva/abc   2./home/shiva/   . 3 ab   Now it creates ab.zip in /home/shiva/  and moves ab.zip in /home/shiva/Backup          Or provide me  your sample paths. will do the same

Comment: I made a small typo error forgot to change backZip.blah to bkZip.blah, now I just have to figure out how to make the script see if said zip file exists in specified path and if it does delete it before moving the new zip over :o thank you!

Comment: @TheCryptek That's Good! and don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you in solving your issue. Keep Coding !

Comment: Would you also be able to help me with it saving the zip file as Zipfile.zip/Users/User/Desktop/Folder instead of saving as ZipFile.zip/Folder

Answer (score 0):

You have to make an absolute path for it probs.

Comment: How do I make it an absolute path if it's on someone else's computer and I don't know the path they used?

Comment: well considering you're not using a GUI system...(Which I think your not) your going to have to prompt them for the path. Normally you'd do the whole "browse" thing but in this case you really can't cause you don't have a GUI.